# Is it possible to use a function to insert the template path for ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

I have tried to use a function to load the path to a template into an `ng-include` directive. I hoped that the argument to my function would render due to its insertion in `ng-include`. But it doesn't work. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div ng-include="'{{content}}'"></div>
...
<div ng-click="showContent('views/my_content.html')">
```

Angular:

```
$scope.showContent = function(attrs){
    $scope.content = attrs;
};
```

When I click on the div that has `ng-click` I can see that `{{content}}` has been replaced with the  template path, but the template itself is not included (i.e., it is not rendered on the page). Is there a way that I can force the template to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-include` does not work like this.

What you need to do is either write another directive that will fetch and show content for you. You could also use `$routeProvider` to change the url and have it include a template URL.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this

```
<div ng-include="'{{content}}'"></div>
```

use this

```
<div ng-include="content"></div>
```

and the template would get rendered.